# Complex tangent bundle but not holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

We know that complex vector bundle needs not to be holomorphic bundle i.e.the transition needs not to be holomorphic.

Is there some example,that manifold has complex tangent bundle but the tangent bundle is not holomorphic?Is there some example that complex vector bundle fails to be holomorphic vector bundle?

Comment: What do you mean by the tangent bundle not being holomorphic?  How do you define a bundle being holomorphic, if the base manifold is not a complex manifold?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, thank you,the base manifold for holomorphic 
vector bundle is always complex manifold ,the tangent bundle for complex manifold is always holomorphic.For base manifold that is not complex,we can also talk about complex vector bundle, is there some smooth manifold that has a complex tangent bundle?

Comment: As wiki :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_vector_bundle shows,A complex vector bundle is a holomorphic vector bundle if X is a complex manifold and if the local trivializations are biholomorphic.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356595/vector-bundle-over-compact-complex-manifold-which-is-not-holomorphic which claims that there are complex vector bundles that do not admit holomorphic structure. And also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7304/complex-vector-bundles-that-are-not-holomorphic which stated that it is an open question for $\mathbb{CP}^n$ for $n>3$.

Comment: For your first question, it doesn't quite make sense the way it is stated now. Because you can't speak of whether a vector bundle is holomorphic without specifying a base complex manifold.

Comment: Yeah,thank you,the comparison between complex vector bundle,and holomorphic bundle should under the complex manifold.  There is another question left:Do you have some example that  non complex manifold has complex vector bundle?Since the definition of the complex vector bundle in the wiki seems does not assume the base manifold be the complex manifold? @lEm

Comment: @yili You can just take any real vector bundle $E$ over any manifold $M$, then complexified it to get $E\otimes \mathbb C$, this always gives you a complex vector bundle.

Comment: thank you,clear.